# Add-on Dev: Extract int value from Blender's enum flag set?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

Is there any way to extract an `int` value from one of Blender's `ENUM_FLAG` properties? Here are the definitions I have:

```
# binary flag values
class OpFlag:
    GA = 1<<0 # activator for asset mode
    LP = 1<<1 # activator for low poly mode
    HP = 1<<2 # activator for high poly mode
    CU = 1<<3 # activator for custom mode

# string based flag values for Blender controls
opflags=[
            ('GA', "Asset", "desc", OpFlag.GA ),
            ('LP', "Low", "desc", OpFlag.LP ),
            ('HP', "High", "desc", OpFlag.HP ),
            ('CU', "Custom", "desc", OpFlag.CU )
        ]

# property using flags
modes : EnumProperty(
    name = "Modes",
    options = {'ENUM_FLAG'},
    items = opflags,
    default={'GA','LP','HP','CU'}
    )
```

This is what I would like to be able to do, if possible:

```
control_op_flags = int( 0 ) # just to make it obvious this is an int
control_op_flags |= int( modes )
```

I read somewhere online that you can cast a Blender string-based enum value to `int`, but it doesn't seem to work with an enum-flags set. This is the error I get:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'set'
```

Does anyone know how to convert an `enum-flags` **set** into a single `int`? I didn't consider it until just now, but is it possible to iterate the set and convert/`OR` all of the values together myself? Would that be the proper way to handle this? I've never iterated a set before, so going to investigate that now.

**Edit Update**: When I try to iterate the set and OR in one entry from it, I get the error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'GA'`.. Sounds like it is dealing with it purely as a string. I'm not sure how to associate it with my `opflags` list.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the value through the RNA properties. Assuming that you have stored `modes` in a *PointerProperty* and assigned to `bpy.types.Scene.demo_tool` (just an example), you can access it in the following way:

The first step is to get access to the RNA properties of `demo_tool` or in general the object that contains your *EnumProperty*. This will give us access to the underlying data structure of `modes` which contains the mapping to the integer values.

```
demo_tool = bpy.context.scene.demo_tool
items = demo_tool.bl_rna.properties["modes"].enum_items
```

The [`enum_items`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.EnumProperty.html#bpy.types.EnumProperty.enum_items) give you access to a collection (`bpy_prop_collection`) of *EnumProperties* which represent the valid (single) flags you can use. It allows a look-up with a key. For example the following code gives you the integer value for your `'LP'` flag, by accessing the [*EnumPropertyItem*](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.EnumPropertyItem.html).

```
items['LP'].value
```

Since you have a set of strings stored in `modes` when using `options={'ENUM_FLAG'}` you must iterate through it to get the integer value for each flag.

```
for flag in demo_tool.modes:
    print(f"{items[flag].value}")
```

Once you have the integers you can perform the boolean logic operations to create a single value.

---

```
import bpy


class DemoSettings(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    GA = 1 << 0  # activator for asset mode
    LP = 1 << 1  # activator for low poly mode
    HP = 1 << 2  # activator for high poly mode
    CU = 1 << 3  # activator for custom mode

    # string based flag values for Blender controls
    opflags = [
        ('GA', "Asset", "desc", GA),
        ('LP', "Low", "desc", LP),
        ('HP', "High", "desc", HP),
        ('CU', "Custom", "desc", CU)
    ]

    # property using flags
    modes: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name="Modes",
        options={'ENUM_FLAG'},
        items=opflags,
        default={'GA', 'LP', 'HP', 'CU'}
    )


class DEMO_PT_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "My own addon"
    bl_category = "Name of your tab"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        demo_tool = context.scene.demo_tool

        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(demo_tool, "modes")

        items = demo_tool.bl_rna.properties["modes"].enum_items

        flag_value = 0

        for flag in demo_tool.modes:
            flag_value |= items[flag].value

        row.label(text=str(flag_value))


classes = (DemoSettings,
           DEMO_PT_panel)


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.Scene.demo_tool = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=DemoSettings)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Your knowledge (and/or ability to find information) is really impressive. Thanks for this detailed answer. For some reason, I keep getting the error `bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "modes" not found`. Would this be because I'm storing "modes" inside of an operator class? Using properties inside of operators is very new for me, so I may be doing something else wrong. I am able to access modes normally, but `self.bl_rna.properties["modes"]` throws this error. Would there be an obvious reason?

Comment: @Robert Thank you! I'd have to look into that.