# How to get an element in a EnumProperty?

Tags: python, properties

I would like to get only 3 third element of an EnumProperty, is a string:

```
myEnum: EnumProperty (name = "Enum", items = searchCallback)
```

`searchCallback` is a function that returns the list to me.

Then the list returns me `("ITEM", "Item", "Item description")`
how can I get "Item description"

`print (self.myEnum)` returns "ITEM" if I try to do `print(self.myEnum[2])` it returns `"E"`.
I don't know if I will use this function but I would still like to find out if this is possible

Comment: Have you tried accessing the [`enum_items`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.EnumProperty.html#bpy.types.EnumProperty.enum_items) through `bl_rna`, similar to [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153362/add-on-dev-extract-int-value-from-blenders-enum-flag-set?rq=1)?

Comment: Interesting, I think I'm following a wrong way for what I should be doing, but I think it's useful to go into this topic too.
Basically the third element would be a directory that is stored, so as to have faster access to that file, since "ITEM" are a file